# How to delete object from collection in magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, delete, object

How to remove any object from magento 2 collection.
If we have collection of products and we want to delete product which is at first index . how to delete that product without deleting it from database?

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('attribute',$somevalue);

foreach ($collection as $key => &$value) {
              if($key == 1){
                //// how to unset this index in collection ?
              }

            }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try below code for deleting it

```
foreach ($collection as $key => $brand) {
   if ($brand->getIsDisabled()) {
      $collection->removeItemByKey($key);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly

```
  $productCollection->removeItemByKey($product->getEntityId());
```

Answer (score -6):

Just try below code

```
<?php 
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('attribute',$somevalue);

foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
              if($key == 1){
               $value->delete(); //Just Use it.
              }

            }
```

Comment: it removes that product from database or not ?

Comment: Yes it will remove products from database if its a collection of product

Comment: Actually i dont want to remove that product from database. I just want to drop it from collection.